# Updates on Main Form after another Form is Closed

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to create a C# Windows Form application. In the main Form I've a button which opens secondary form using `ShowDialog()` which makes some updates on the database. When user saves data and closes that form, I need to update my `ListView` on main Form from database. How to trigger updates on ListView when secondary Form is closed? I tried mouse events to make update on `ListView` but that is a bit late. Is there any event which I can use to achieve this?

Comment: `FormClosing` event might help you in this..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use ShowDialog() than execution continues from next string after the form was closed:

```
var updateForm = new UpdateForm();
updateForm.ShowDialog();

// Here it was closed
UpdateMainForm();
```

Comment: Right... The ShowDialog() method is a blocking call.

Comment: Yeah. This will solve the question. Easy solution and question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to update listview on main form as soon as user is done with changes in sub form and closes it.

If that is true, main form can subscribe a handler to subform.closing event.
And in the event handler you can update listview from database.

Do not forget to unsubscribe the handler from subform.closing.